# Relation between a matrix and a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have conceptual question. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{F}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}$, and let $B_V = (v_1, ... , v_n)$ and $B_U = (u_1, ... , u_n)$ be bases of $\mathbb{F}^n$, and let $A$ be an $n \times n $ matrix. Must there be a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$ such that $[T]^{B_V}_{B_U} = A$? and if so, how will we define $T$?

Comment: If $x = \sum \alpha_i v_i $, then $T(x) = \sum \alpha_i T(v_i) = \sum \alpha_i u_i$?

Comment: @Andrew not necessarily, but assume that that is the situtation - does it imply that rank(A) = n?

Comment: Here's an attempt at an answer. $A = [T]^{B_V}_{B_U} = [id]^{E}_{B_U} \cdot [T]^{E}_{E} \cdot [id]^{B_V}_{E}$ where E is the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$, so therefore $[T]^{E}_{E} = [id]^{B_U}_{E} \cdot A \cdot [id]^{E}_{B_V}$. Is that a sufficient way to define $T$?

Comment: What do you consider sufficient? Anyway, if you feel like you have an answer, I suggest you post it as an answer!

Comment: I mean does that ensures T is a linear transformation?

Comment: Take a look here: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices). That page should answer your questions, but if it doesn't, then feel free to ping me again.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion in the comments does the work. Alternatively, write $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ and define $T$ by the formula

$$ T \left( \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i \right) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n c_i a_{ji} u_j$$

and check that $[T]^{B_V}_{B_U} = A$.